# how to make the appended clone disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with my appended cloned `tr`, my clone working properly but I can't get disable it and whenever I add the disabled syntax in the condition it disabled the inputted `tr`, and the cloned `tr`

[Code Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Mikhail723/wq8zo3gc/14/)

sample code where I having a hard time

```
$('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36"]').on('change', function() {

  var $this = $(this)
  console.log(index)
  var data_column = $this.attr('data-column');
  var index = $('#Table_2').find(`input[data-column="${data_column}"]`).index($this)
  var addrow = $('#Table_2 tbody tr').get(index);

  var parentTr = $(addrow).prop('disabled', true).closest('tr');
  console.log(addrow)
  var difval = $(addrow).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc"]').val();

  if (difval == '0') {

    $(addrow).find('input').prop('disabled', true)

  } else {

    for (let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
      $(parentTr).clone().insertAfter($(parentTr));
    }
  }

  console.log(difval)
});
```

Please help me

Comment: Which jquery version are you used? have you tried with `.attr("disabled", 'disabled')`

Comment: 3.4.1 and nope did not tried it

Comment: @tafreets Your problem is both cloned and already existed `tr` got disabled? Am I right?

Comment: Your code clearly set disabled against the original row.   Clone then apply disabled to the the clone only.

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie yes

Comment: @freedomn-m heheh thats the problem i don't where i gonna put  the disabled symtax

Comment: `var parentTr = $(addrow).prop('disabled', true)` -> `var parentTr = $(addrow);` so it doesn't disable the source row.  Then `$(parentTr).clone()` -> `var newrow = $(parentTr).clone(); newrow.attr("disabled", true); parentTr.after(newrow);`  or `$(parentTr).clone().attr("disabled", true).insertAfter($(parentTr));`

Comment: @freedomn-m i already fix it, the syntax i use is, find('input).prop('disabled', true) and i put in the forloop statement

Comment: If you have a solution, please either close the question or, if you feel it would be useful to future visitors, add the solution as an answer and marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36"]', function() {
var parentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
var table1 = parent.$('#Table_1').closest('tr');
var difval = parentTr.find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc"]').val();

if (difval > 0){
var copy = parentTr.clone().insertAfter(parentTr);
copy.find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j"],input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9"],input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36"]').val('');
copy.find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq"]').val(difval);
parentTr.find('input').prop('disabled', true).css('background', 'lightgreen');

}
parentTr.find('input').prop('disabled', true).css('background', 'lightgreen');
});
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).